# auto scaling in spark cassandra cluster with zero downtime

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, autoscaling

how to add or remove spark cassandra cluster resources (workers, executors, cores, memory etc.) dynamically based on workload? can we predict cluster resources before deploying? what can be done with data when doing scaling down/ remove the nodes from the cluster.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by predicting cluster resources before deploying? What kind of cluster are you running? Spark standalone, YARN, Mesos? What kind of nodes to you want to remove? Spark executors? Cassandra nodes?

Comment: cluster is spark YARN. as per my understanding add/remove executers is supported by spark dynamic allocation in lets say 4 node cluster. but is it support stretch or squeeze the cluster size. can we add/remove spark worker nodes and cassandra nodes separately? if yes then how to do it. what exactly triggers addition/removal of spark workers and cassandra nodes?

Comment: for an example: i started with 4 node spark cassandra cluster and every day 100GB data is coming than how to manage cluster?

Comment: i mean how to resize the spark cassandra cluster based on current workload. if multiple users can deploy memory intensive/cpu intensive spark jobs to the cluster, then can we calculate/ predict job exe time or workload before submitting spark jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Spark supports dynamic allocation of workers with lots of configuration options, please refer to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation

Short version:

- Spark can allocate new executors when task queue is full
- Spark will deallocate executors when they have been idle for some time
- Executors will be allocated with the amount of cores/memory that has been set at startup, so chose wisely
- Caching will be affected by dynamic allocation (mostly executors being deallocated)

Comment: Thank you. i am basically interested in add/remove nodes in spark cassandra cluster by retaining data locality.